# Add style programatically to table row

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I am trying to add style to a table row in C# code. However, as simple as it may seem, I caanot find the proper way to do it. The code for my table is

```
<table width="100%" style="vertical-align:top; height:170px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 

    <tr id="trTasks" runat="server" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#eaeaea';" onmouseout="this.bgColor='#FFFFFF';" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"/>

</table>
```

I would like to set a different background color for trTasks when a condition is fullfiled. I've tried doing it like this:

```
trCompletedTasks.Attributes.Add("CssClass", "SelectedItem");
```

and

```
trCompletedTasks.Style.Add("CssClass", "SelectedItem");
```

but none of these seems to work.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML attribute is named `class`:

```
trCompletedTasks.Attributes.Add("class", "SelectedItem");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get a row to change color when the mouse is over it, all modern browsers will let you do it just using CSS rather than on the server end. Just define a style with the desired background color for `.yourtable tr:hover`, and you'll be good to go.

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vdy6q/.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misread your question. This doesn't do what you wanted it to, but it could replace that javascript you have embedded in every `tr` element. Much cleaner this way.

Comment: Your answer is very useful, I also need to do that! Thank you very much for your reply.